# Completely Clear CMake Cache (Qt Creator)

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I have come to this problem several times: Something on my system has changed so cmake got confused and cannot parse the project anymore.
When I just setup everything from scratch it works.

What I tried to solve the problem was following:

- delete cmake cache
- delete everything in the build folder
- delete the cmakelist.txt.user
- run cmake again -> problem still there

The only way I could solve it was to make a new build folder and set up the project from scratch, because some settings were still somewhere saved for the old build folder.

So where are those corrupted settings stored? and how can I reset them without having to change the folder??

Comment: What makes you confident the issue is cmake and not qt-creator? Also what generator are you using?

Comment: @hdf89shfdfs You're right, it also could be that it is some QtCreator issue. So where would i clean that up? I'm using Unix-Makefiles.